# rosseria_arduino ros_lib permission denied

Tags: ros, arduino, ros-lib, rosserial, libraries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm new in ROS and I'm trying to setup rosserial arduino following the steps of the tutorial:

```
    cd <ws>/src
    git clone https://github[dot]com/ros-drivers/rosserial.git
   `cd <ws>`
  catkin_make
  catkin_make install
  source <ws>/install/setup.bash

    cd <sketchbook>/libraries
  rm -rf ros_lib
  rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .
```

but when I enter the last command I get this error message:

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/jaime/sketchbook/libraries/ros_lib'
```

I need to know what to do in this case.
Thank you very much!

Apparently is about a permission to make a folder into the ~/sketchbook/libraries folderbecause I can run the same last code outside that folder and it works.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65726/rosseria_arduino-ros_lib-permission-denied/) by [Jaime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5209/jaime/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This isn't really a ROS issue - as the error message says, it's an issue with the permissions in that directory. See if reading [this](http://www.linux.org/article/view/file-permissions-chmod) tutorial on Linux file permissions helps, and then check out "man chmod".

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jaime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5209/jaime/) on 2013-06-22**:
This actually solve the problem! I just insert a command to give me the permissions to write, read and execute the ~/sketchbook/libraries folder, it went like this: sudo chmod 777 ~/sketchbook/libraries. Thanks!